# AWS Lambda - Run Lambda multiply times with different environment variables

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that uses 2 environment variables. I want to run this lambda up to several hundred times a day, however i need to change the environment variables between runs.

Ideally, I would like something where I could a list a set of variables pairs and run the lambdas on a schedule

The only way I see of doing this, is have separate lambdas and setting the environment variables for each manually

Any Ideas about how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an SQS queue for this. Instead of your scheduler initiating the Lambda function directly, it could simply send a message with the two data values to an SQS queue, and the SQS queue could be configured to trigger the Lambda. When triggered, the Lambda will receive the data from the message. So, the Lambda function does not need to change.

Of course, if you have complete control over the client that generates the two data values then that client could also simply invoke the Lambda function directly, passing the two data values in the payload.

Comment: That looks like what i wanted.Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use CloudWatch scheduled events to trigger the lambda? You can set two events with different inputs, and the lambda will behave differently with different inputs.

Comment: @BenjaminHao I was assuming that there would, in the general case, be more than two distinct pairs of values. For example, if there were 100 distinct pairs, you wouldn't want to configure 100 scheduled events. But for a handful, yes that would also work.

Comment: @jarmod I totally agree. I think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: There could be potentially hundreds of events

Comment: I found a better option was SNS, but this really put me on the right track. The issue with SQS was that is constantly polling. wasting my usage, when this is going to be a set of lambda run once daily